# How to have two different modal

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I have two different modals in my view and because of the first one, the second one doesn't work.

Have a look at it please:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("newAddressModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("modal-button");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
var modal2 = document.getElementById("cancelModal");

var btn2 = document.getElementById("cancelOrder");

function openModalOrders() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

So when it is clicked I am getting **main.js:303 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined**

Thanks...

Comment: `window.onclick =` you are overriding the previous onclick.  If you want to attach multiple events use `addEventListener` instead,..  It's the more modern way to do it anyway..

Comment: I change it a little bit. Could you please have a look? It still doesnt work

Comment: What's on line 303?

Comment: this: modal.style.display = "none";

Comment: check if `modal` isn't `undefined`. If `document.getElementById("newAddressModal");` returns undefined, if means there are no elements with id `newAddressModal`